# XML datatype function does not exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

So I have this bit of sql that grabs a XML nodes whose content is encoded html. I then converted that into a varchar and "decode" it and cast it back into an XML data type. The problem that I have is when I call the nodes function it says that `"nodes" is not a valid function, property, or field.`. The weird thing is that if use the other [functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) `query`, `value`,`exist`, and `modify` it does not complain. Any ideas as to why?

```
Declare @XmlEl As XML
DECLARE @htmlString As varchar(max)
Select @XmlEl = CAST(replace(CAST(Body AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'utf-16', 'utf-8') AS xml) FROM Templates where TemplateID = 3119
Set @XmlEl = @XmlEl.query('/PdfTemplate/PdfBody').query('string(/)')
Select CAST(@XmlEl As varchar(max))
Set @htmlString = Replace(CAST(@XmlEl As varchar(max)), '&lt;', '<')
Set @XmlEl = CAST(Replace(@htmlString, '&gt;', '>') AS XML)
Select @XmlEl.nodes('p/span')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can just do a SELECT off of @XmlEl.nodes like that.  I believe you need something more like

```
Select x.a.query('.') FROM @XmlEl.nodes('p/span') x(a)
```

Referenced from [MSDN nodes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)